# What is "dummy" in CREATE PROCEDURE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm doing investigation of code repo and find one thing that make me confused. SQL Server stored procedures are contained in a repo as a set of queries with following structure:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[sp_ProcTitle]', N'P') IS NULL
BEGIN
    EXEC dbo.sp_executeSQL N'CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ProcTitle] AS dummy:;';
END

ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.sp_ProcTitle 
    @ParamOne int, 
    @ParamTwo date, 
    @ParamThree int
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON

     -- some procedure body

END
```

Never before I saw `AS dummy:;` and now I'm a little confused, I can't find any good explanation what is it and how it works. Could anybody tell me what does it mean this statement? How it works? What is the reason to have it? Any thought would be good to hear. Or, please, advise me some link where I can find good explanation.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: I think it would have been be clearer if the author of the script created the "dummy" stored procedure stub with `AS RETURN;` instead of specifying a label `AS dummy:`.

Comment: Its not material here but I also use `dummy:` when I want a placeholder in a `begin end` where I have commented out the contents temporarily: `begin dummy: /* more lines */ end` And of course `dummy` can be any text that may serve as a valid label.

Comment: As others have explained, it's an empty SP. The author may be using `dummy:` as a marker that they can search for to find unfinished work, similar to `-- TBD.` or `-- ?????`. Something easy to do with [`sp_helptext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-helptext-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is simply a label, such that could be used in a `GOTO` statement.

The word "dummy" is unimportant. It's simply trying to create the stored procedure if it doesn't exist, with a minimal amount of text. The content is then filled in with the ALTER.

Conceivably, the `dummy` text could later be searched for to see if any procedures were created and didn't have their content filled in, to check against failed deployments, etc.

Why do this? Well, it preserve the creation time of the stored procedure in metadata (which can be useful in administration or tracking down problems), and is compatible with versions of SQL Server that lack the `CREATE OR ALTER...` support.

Comment: The minimum amount of text would be `CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ProcTitle] As` - there is no requirement to enter any body at all

Comment: @MartinSmith that's correct, I didn't mean to suggest it was an absolute minimum. sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

This might make a little more sense if we add a little formatting to the `CREATE`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ProcTitle]
AS
    dummy:
```

This is, effectively, an empty procedure with a label called `dummy`. The user appears to be using this to ensure that the procedure exists first, and the `ALTER`ing it. In older versions of SQL Server, such methods were needed because it didn't support `CREATE OR ALTER` syntax. As such, if you tried to `ALTER` a procedure that didn't exist the statement failed, and likewise if you try to `CREATE` a procedure that already exists it fails.

If you are on a recent version of SQL Server, I'd suggest changing to `CREATE OR ALTER` and getting rid of the call to `sys.sp_executesql`.